# How to access cell inside UITableView in iOS automation

Tags: javascript, iphone, ios, ipad, ios-ui-automation

I need help accessing cell (name:Settings) inside UITableView. I am doing ios-UIAutomation on ipad v6.0.1.

I tried with all these commands -

1. `mainWindow.popover().tableViews()[0].cells()[4].tap();`
2. `mainWindow.tableViews()[0].cells()["Settings"].tap();`
3. `mainWindow.popover().tableViews()[0].cells()[4].elements()["Settings"];`

but nothing worked.

The logElementTree looks like this -

```
UIATarget  
   | UIAApplication
      | UIAWindow
         | UIAPopover
            | UIATableView : name:Empty list
               | UIATableCell : name:Menu
               | **UIATableCell : name:Settings**
```

Attaching screenshot of logTree for reference.

Comment: Did you try this?: `mainWindow.popover().tableViews()[0].cells()["Settings"].tap();`

It looks like you left out the "popover()" in that one.

Comment: Yeah,tried this also. For everything - I am getting -> Script threw an uncaught Javascript error : 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'mainWindow.popover.tableViews()')

Comment: That error seems to indicate that you left the parentheses off of the `popover()` method. Try it with the parens and post the error here if it doesn't work.

Comment: I forgot to add parenthesis after popover. It worked now. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I'd suggest adding a name to the table view itself. Using array offsets makes it harder to maintain your test code. It's 'standard' practice to define variables for the top level items.

I believe this code will work. Working within the JavaScript 'framework' in Instruments is an exercise in frustration. I've found naming the intermediate objects is a good starting point.

```
var target = UIATarget.localTarget();
var app = target.frontMostApp();
var mainWindow = app.mainWindow();

var targetTableView = mainWindow.popover.tableViews()[0];   

targetTableView().cells()["Settings"].tap()
```

Answer (score 0):

The variable `targetTableView()` is not a method , so parentheses are not needed:

```
targetTableView.cells()["Settings"].tap()
```

When I declare a variable `targetTableView`, I have no method of `popover` , so this method is not assigned:

```
var targetTableView = mainWindow.tableViews()[0];
```